# Nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, eclipselink

I have a class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@Data
public class MovieEntity implements Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MovieRate> ratings;
}
```

which maps the list

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies_ratings")
@Data
public class MovieRate {
    ...
}
```

while loading `movie.getRatings()` the list throws me out

```
    ...
at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet.buildDelegate(IndirectSet.java:225) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet.getDelegate(IndirectSet.java:436) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectSet.hashCode(IndirectSet.java:485) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at com.core.jpa.entity.MovieEntity.hashCode(MovieEntity.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.core.jpa.entity.movie.MovieRate.hashCode(MovieRate.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:968) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.0.jar:na]
...
```

All wrong https://pastebin.com/RgNg84Cb

The problem is probably with the Lombok annotations. But I do not know what.

Comment: Post the hashCode of both classes

Comment: does `MovieRate` have an association back to `MovieEntity`?

Comment: @O.Badr mapped by movie ? ManyToOne
    private MovieEntity movie;

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos 
Annotation Data generated a hashCode.

Comment: You look to have a stackoverflow there, post it

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the exception is caused by both `MovieRate.hashcode()` and `MovieEntity.hascode()` which is generated by [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), to solve your issue you may add `@EqualsAndHashCode` in `MovieRate` or in `MovieEntity` or both :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@Data @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "ratings")
public class MovieEntity implements Serializable {
    // Your code
}
```

or

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies_ratings")
@Data @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "movie")
public class MovieRate {
    ...
}
```

Why? [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) (as it use [@EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)) in order to generate `hashCode()`:

> By default, it'll use all non-static, non-transient fields

So it will use `MovieEntity.ratings` and `MovieRate.movie` as well, and each call of `hashCode()` method of the one side will call the other side's `hashCode()`, and as it's bidirectional association, it will run infinitely till `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

**Note:** You will have the same error for `toString()` (which also generated by `@Data`) method for both entities, as each one will attempt to print the other side. To solve it, you can add [@ToString](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) to exclude the same fields.